# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getInputStream() after getReader() has already been called for the current request

Tags: java, interceptor

I wrote interceptor:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    log.info("[pre-handle] method: {}\tURL: {}", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL());
    if (HttpMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod())) {
        log.info(request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining()));
    }
    return true;
}
```

but when I try to call controller, exception throws:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call getInputStream() after
>   getReader() has already been called for the current request

as I understand, getReader() calling closes InputStream & nothing comes to controller.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read request multiple time you will need to cache your request before it is read the 1st time. More info can be read [here](http://www.javabyexamples.com/read-request-body-multiple-times-using-spring-mvc/).

Spring MVC provides the ContentCachingRequestWrapper class. 
It is a wrapper around the original HttpServletRequest object.

To use it, we must first create a web filter which wraps the original HttpServletRequest:

```
@Component
public class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest currentRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(currentRequest);
        chain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

After which you can get the byte[] content using the getContentAsByteArray method of ContentCachingRequestWrapper in your interceptor.

Comment: How could you access the ContentCachingRequestWrapper from other controller?. It couldn't be injected since it's not a @Component too.